# The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly. What to do?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting this error:

> The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ReadNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean nested)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXamlElementFor(IElementNode node, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParser.ParseXaml(RootNode rootNode, XmlReader reader)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.ParseXaml(Stream stream, TypeReference typeReference)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I know that it is saying that the item is duplicated but I scanned whole project with Total Commander and I didn't find any duplicated file.

Comment: Show some relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just have an error in your XAML page. "An item with the same key has already been added." might be some duplicate property.

Comment: Without seeing the code...it's almost certainly a duplicate style or resource of some kind.

Comment: yeah also had such error with a duplicate resource entry in App.xaml <Application.Resources>

Comment: Is there some way to automatically find code duplication ? I tried using Visual Studio 2017 Analyze functions but I don't have Analyze Solution for Code Clones function. Thanks !

Comment: Not sure, just what i would do if i hope you are using source control is to revert changes made recently until problem gone, then start applying changes until problem appears, to find the cause.. *sigh*

Comment: I resolved it. I found problem file in project %TEMP% folder. Thanks for your help !

Comment: A Xaml error was my problem too. I had a duplicate `<StackLayout.Children>` tag. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975859/the-xamlctask-task-failed-unexpectedly-in-xamarin/47466070#47466070]

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate your nuGet-packages and make sure all Xamarin.Forms referencing projects uses the same Xamarin.Forms version. After that empty the packages folder, clean and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually happens when there is error in compiling of your xaml code. Check the code recently added.